# Rust equivalent of Python Future (i.e. with set_result() method)

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

Is there a struct in some well-known utilities crate that does what Python's `asyncio.Future` does, i.e has a `.set_result(value)` method, and will be pending indefinitely until some other task calls that method, at which point it resolves to that value?

I've recreated this functionality by reading the docs on how Rust futures work but I'm still a bit new to this and my code is a bit clunky and likely buggy and has some restrictions I believe are unnecessary, but the compiler isn't smart enough to prove otherwise and neither am I.  I believe I stumbled across similar functionality in a public crate a while back but I can't remember what it was called.

Comment: A [oneshot channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/fn.channel.html)? Rust futures are general-purpose abstraction for an asynchronous computation. A oneshot channel has a receiver which implements `Future`, and that future will resolve when the `Sender` is used.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a asynchronous oneshot channel, i.e. the receiver-sender pair, where receiver can be awaited until the value is pushed into the sender. If you want to do this in a runtime-agnostic way, you probably want [`futures::channel::oneshot`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/channel/oneshot/index.html).